# Algorithms and techniques for "unclustering" map features with OpenLayers

Tags: geometry, cluster-analysis, geospatial, openlayers

I'm working with OpenLayers (though the advice I need is more general) to create an "unclustering" behavior.

Instead of collapsing multiple features that are close to each other at a given zoom level into a single feature, I want to do the opposite:  Push those features apart so each can be visually legible.  For my application (a traceroute visualisation app), the precise location of a feature when zoomed out is basically irrelevant, but seeing each feature (and label) clearly, is of utmost importance.

For two features, the technique seems trivial (find the line defined by the two features and push away along that line).  But what about more than two features?  My geometry is weak -- I feel like this must be a solved problem with a simple solution, but I don't know what magic words to use to even start my research. Where should I be looking to learn how to do this? What techniques are known to be fast and stable?

Bonus points if you can point me to resources that will help not only with pushing the features away, but with changing label position to keep the features as close to their correct geographic position.

Comment: Assuming your features are rectangular (little text boxes?) you want a method of placing N features such that they don't overlap and minimises the distance between the feature's point coordinate and the position of the rectangle? This might be ridiculously hard for a large number of rectangles (lookup graph layout algorithms). However you cut it, I'd probably have the labels have a line connecting them to the coordinate point, since the label boxes could be miles away from their true position...

Comment: @Spacedman: You got it -- I want to (re)place N features such that they don't overlap with minimal distance between them (or possibly a user specified factor).  In my case there will rarely be more than ~5 overlapping features even when zoomed way out. The features themselves are actually simply points (styled as circles).  The label idea makes a great deal of sense, but the way labels are associated with features in OpenLayers may make that hard if not impossible, so I was going to use the rectangle defined by feature + label. "Graph layout algorithms" will be my next avenue of research.

Comment: The big picture problem is that moving feature A because it overlaps feature B might shift it over feature C or D. You pretty much have to either solve the whole thing in one go or adopt a step-wise heuristic where features push each other about - that's the connection to graph layout algorithms anyway. Graph layout is usually more about reducing overlapping connections...

Comment: Yup -- which is why it is trivial in the n=2 objects case, and gets scary beyond that. But it also looks like I could implement a forced-directed graphing algorithm (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force-based_algorithms_%28graph_drawing%29).  You should post this as the answer since it was your original comment that helped me find this, and you deserve some karma for it!